# calendar does not work

Tags: visualforce, calendar

I have a Vf page with Date field.  when i click the calender will display and from where i can choose my date.

But it get displayed only fist selection. eg: When i try to select the date for 1st time the calender get displayed but from the next time it did not. This is problem is only with Chrome and firefox(version is 19) but same page get work with firefox browser version is 16. In IE it get worked fine. Do anyone know what might be wrong with this VF page.

Comment: Does calendar widget work OK for you on standard page layouts? If it does - you probably have a bit of javascript that interferes with it on your Visualforce page, you'd have to post some code. Open javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome) and check if there are any errors?

Answer (score 1):

By default, this functionality should work. You should be able to select a date field, deselect it, and select it again and the calendar should work.

My guess is that @eyescream was correct in his assertion that you most likely have some custom Javascript that is conflicting with this. When you error out Javascript, it usually stops the rest of the Javascript from functioning.

Without seeing if you have custom Javascript, your best bet is to check your Javascript console and see if you are getting errors.